# Matching multiple groups of characters with python's regular expressions

Tags: python, regex

As part of some lemmatization rules, I'm trying to form a regular expression that will match strings ending in 'ses', 'zes', 'xes', 'ches' or 'shes' and I'm having difficulty getting the letter groupings correct.  I thought the following would work...

```
re.fullmatch(r'.*[szx(ch)(sh)]es\b', infl)
```

but I see that this will match 'ces' or 'hes word endings where I only want it to match 'ches' word endings (same for the (sh) grouping).  I must be misunderstanding how to 'or' together groups correctly.  Whenever I put a bracket around a set of groups I match all letters inside, not just the letter combos.

How can I reform the `fullmatch` expression to work correctly?  I must be misunderstanding how combining groupings work so a short explanation of that, in this context, would also be helpful.

BTW... I only need a true/false return.  I'm not interested in the returned values.

Some matching examples are: dismisses, waltzes, indexes, detaches, distinguishes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex does not work correctly even in Java as groupings are not supported inside character classes. The `(` and `)` are treated as literal parentheses inside `[...]`.

The `fullmatch` requires a full string match, and if you do not care what was at the start just use `re.search` and anchor the pattern at the end.

Use

```
re.search(r'(?:[zx]|ch|sh?)es$', s)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dljlaP/1) and a [Regulex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=(%3F%3A%5Bzx%5D%7Cch%7Csh%3F)es%24):

[image]

**Details**

- `(?:[zx]|ch|sh?)` - a [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-do) matching either of

  - `[zx]` - `z` or `x`
  - `|` - or
  - `ch` - `ch` char sequence
  - `|` - or
  - `sh?` - `s` or `sh`
- `es` - `es` substring
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Why ?: Without remembering sign is needed here ?

Comment: @srknzl It is best practice to use a non-capturing group when you do not need to access the group value after matching.

Comment: This rules should not match strings with 'ess" on the end.  That's a different lemmatization rule.

Comment: Can I ask whether or not python and JavaScript regex are using the same syntax? At regulex graph site it says JavaScript regex visualizer at the top. Is it for python? Thanks

Comment: @srknzl Those are different regex engines but this exact pattern will work the same in both languages.

Comment: @bivouac0 The regex [does not match](https://regex101.com/r/dljlaP/4) strings ending with `ess`. Your `r'.*[szx(ch)(sh)]es\b'` pattern (that you say works in Java, although it does not) does not contain any quotation  marks. Please share a regex fiddle showing your real problem.

Comment: @SanV There are no quotes in the original pattern.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  fair enough.  respect to Wiktor, the wizard / regexp.ert :)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It's possible the java version has some issues.  It's from code that I assumed worked but maybe it's bugged or I'm misunderstanding what they intended.  I'll edit the post to remove the java comment.

Comment: @bivouac0 Better add the matching and non-matching examples.